# Placing JDBC Driver to work with Java class In a Webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Im trying to set up the JDBC driver to work with a Webapp. I did manage to make it work with my java class but it must be aside from the webapp. In a single project apart while compiling in Netbeans. I've to make it work with a webpp using Tomcat. Im in the part of validating user login info using the data stored in the Database. I send the user info to the server side (Java class) to validate as I'm in favor of not using scriplets in the JSPs so I dont want to re-code the same functions I have in my Java class. Where do I put the driver so that it can be used in the Java class in webapp? I tried in Tomcat/lib and Tomcat/common/lib. Im using LINUX Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you loading and obtaining the driver in your code using the standard JDBC methods within your web application or are you using the container's pools via the _web.xml_ or _context.xml_?

Comment: Using standard JDBC methods for now. Haven't really gotten into .xml yet!

Answer (score 2):

In your webapp under `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: I tried your answer and it didn't work. But thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the folder. For future users in need, you must place your JDBC driver in:

```
                        **/usr/share/tomcat7/lib**
```

NOTE: This is in Linux Ubuntu.